ERROR: Failed building wheel for imagededup
I need to install this package to build an image recognition tool.
I tried reinstalling Python and also Visual Studio Build Tools, but cannot successfully install Imagededup. It always gives me the wheel error.
I am driving nuts but my skills are basic so might be missing something basic.
I am using Python 3.12.1
`C:\Users\r.sousa>pip install imagededup
Collecting imagededup
  Using cached imagededup-0.3.1.tar.gz (20.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting torch (from imagededup)
  Using cached torch-2.3.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (26 kB)
Collecting torchvision (from imagededup)
  Using cached torchvision-0.18.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (6.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow>=9.0 in c:\users\r.sousa\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from imagededup) (10.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in c:\users\r.sousa\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from imagededup) (4.66.1)
Collecting scikit-learn (from imagededup)
  Using cached scikit_learn-1.4.2-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (11 kB)
Collecting PyWavelets (from imagededup)
  Using cached pywavelets-1.6.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (9.0 kB)
Collecting matplotlib (from imagededup)
  Using cached matplotlib-3.8.4-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (5.9 kB)
Collecting contourpy>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib->imagededup)
  Using cached contourpy-1.2.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)
Collecting cycler>=0.10 (from matplotlib->imagededup)
  Using cached cycler-0.12.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
Collecting fonttools>=4.22.0 (from matplotlib->imagededup)`
  Using cached fonttools-4.51.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (162 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.3.1 (from matplotlib->imagededup)
  Using cached kiwisolver-1.4.5-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (6.5 kB)
Collecting numpy>=1.21 (from matplotlib->imagededup)
  Using cached numpy-1.26.4-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (61 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in c:\users\r.sousa\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->imagededup) (23.2)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.3.1 (from matplotlib->imagededup)
  Using cached pyparsing-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.1 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.7 (from matplotlib->imagededup)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.9.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.4 kB)
Collecting scipy>=1.6.0 (from scikit-learn->imagededup)
  Using cached scipy-1.13.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (60 kB)
Collecting joblib>=1.2.0 (from scikit-learn->imagededup)
  Using cached joblib-1.4.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.4 kB)
Collecting threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 (from scikit-learn->imagededup)
  Using cached threadpoolctl-3.5.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (13 kB)
Collecting filelock (from torch->imagededup)
  Using cached filelock-3.14.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4.8.0 in c:\users\r.sousa\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from torch->imagededup) (4.9.0)
Collecting sympy (from torch->imagededup)
  Using cached sympy-1.12-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (12 kB)
Collecting networkx (from torch->imagededup)
  Using cached networkx-3.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.1 kB)
Collecting jinja2 (from torch->imagededup)
  Using cached jinja2-3.1.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.6 kB)
Collecting fsspec (from torch->imagededup)
  Using cached fsspec-2024.3.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.8 kB)
Collecting mkl<=2021.4.0,>=2021.1.1 (from torch->imagededup)
  Using cached mkl-2021.4.0-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\r.sousa\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from tqdm->imagededup) (0.4.6)
Collecting intel-openmp==2021.* (from mkl<=2021.4.0,>=2021.1.1->torch->imagededup)
  Using cached intel_openmp-2021.4.0-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.2 kB)
Collecting tbb==2021.* (from mkl<=2021.4.0,>=2021.1.1->torch->imagededup)
  Using cached tbb-2021.12.0-py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.1 kB)
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib->imagededup)
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.8 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0 (from jinja2->torch->imagededup)
  Using cached MarkupSafe-2.1.5-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (3.1 kB)
Collecting mpmath>=0.19 (from sympy->torch->imagededup)
  Using cached mpmath-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.6 kB)
Using cached matplotlib-3.8.4-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (7.7 MB)
Using cached pywavelets-1.6.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (4.2 MB)
Using cached scikit_learn-1.4.2-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (10.6 MB)
Using cached torch-2.3.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (159.7 MB)
Using cached torchvision-0.18.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (1.2 MB)
Using cached contourpy-1.2.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (189 kB)
Using cached cycler-0.12.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.3 kB)
Using cached fonttools-4.51.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (2.2 MB)
Using cached joblib-1.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (301 kB)
Using cached kiwisolver-1.4.5-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (56 kB)
Using cached mkl-2021.4.0-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl (228.5 MB)
Using cached intel_openmp-2021.4.0-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl (3.5 MB)
Using cached tbb-2021.12.0-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (286 kB)
Using cached numpy-1.26.4-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (15.5 MB)
Using cached pyparsing-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (103 kB)
Using cached python_dateutil-2.9.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (229 kB)
Using cached scipy-1.13.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (45.9 MB)
Using cached threadpoolctl-3.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Using cached filelock-3.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Using cached fsspec-2024.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (171 kB)
Using cached jinja2-3.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Using cached networkx-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 MB)
Using cached sympy-1.12-py3-none-any.whl (5.7 MB)
Using cached MarkupSafe-2.1.5-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (17 kB)
Using cached mpmath-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (536 kB)
Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: imagededup
  Building wheel for imagededup (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for imagededup (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [51 lines of output]
      C:\Users\r.sousa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-lq7qgxmg\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:476: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: Invalid dash-separated options
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future
              versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead.

              By 2024-Sep-26, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
              or your builds will no longer be supported.

              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        opt = self.warn_dash_deprecation(opt, section)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup
      copying imagededup\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\evaluation
      copying imagededup\evaluation\evaluation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\evaluation
      copying imagededup\evaluation\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\evaluation
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\handlers
      copying imagededup\handlers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\handlers
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\methods
      copying imagededup\methods\cnn.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\methods
      copying imagededup\methods\hashing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\methods
      copying imagededup\methods\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\methods
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\utils
      copying imagededup\utils\data_generator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\utils
      copying imagededup\utils\general_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\utils
      copying imagededup\utils\image_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\utils
      copying imagededup\utils\logger.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\utils
      copying imagededup\utils\plotter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\utils
      copying imagededup\utils\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\utils
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\handlers\metrics
      copying imagededup\handlers\metrics\classification.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\handlers\metrics
      copying imagededup\handlers\metrics\information_retrieval.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\handlers\metrics
      copying imagededup\handlers\metrics\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\handlers\metrics
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\handlers\search
      copying imagededup\handlers\search\bktree.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\handlers\search
      copying imagededup\handlers\search\brute_force.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\handlers\search
      copying imagededup\handlers\search\brute_force_cython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\handlers\search
      copying imagededup\handlers\search\retrieval.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\handlers\search
      copying imagededup\handlers\search\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\imagededup\handlers\search
      running build_ext
      building 'brute_force_cython_ext' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for imagededup
Failed to build imagededup
ERROR: Could not build wheels for imagededup, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

C:\Users\r.sousa>python pip install pyproject.toml-based
python: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\r.sousa\\pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

C:\Users\r.sousa>pip install pyproject.toml-based
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyproject.toml-based (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyproject.toml-based````

I need to install this package to build a image recognition tool.
I tried reinstalling Python and also Visual Studio Build Tools but cannot sucessfully install Imagededup, always gives me the wheel error.
I am driving nuts but my skills are basic so might be missing something basic.


this error typically occurs when the Python package contains a C extension module (in your case, brute_force_cython_ext) that needs to be compiled during installation. The compiler required to build these C extensions on Windows is Microsoft Visual C++.
In-order to resolve your issue, you need to install Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools 14.0 or greater, which includes the necessary compiler. You can download it from  https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Thanks for the help but I do have the last version of the build tools. I tried to install it again, restart, and still face the same error.

If that's the case, then most probably the issues might be either with your python version, or the env variables are not being accessed correctly, you can try to check with a lower version of python or if the path variables are correctly added.
Also you can simply install it directly through the Github source.

Apparently the brute_force_cython_ext extension cannot be compiled with your setup. While this needs to be fixed somewhere else, you could consider using Python 3.11 for now. I was able to install the imagededup package on Linux using Python 3.11.7, and on Windows using Python 3.11.8.

Thanks will try with previous python version

Alternatively you could try out the second recommended way of installing imagededup, i.e. installing it from the GitHub source (see the Imagededup homepage for detailed installation instructions). I succeeded installing it this way under Linux with Python 3.12.1.
